# foreach function not working correctly

Tags: php, loops, foreach, copy

The foreach function is not working as I expect:

```
<?php

$folders = scandir('../Users/');  
foreach($folders as $item):
    if ((substr($item, 0, 1) == '.') || (preg_match("/\.php$/", $item)))
          continue;

     if (is_dir("../Users/$item"))
          $target_folders = @scandir("../Users/$item/processed/");
     foreach($target_folders as $target_item){

         if ((!preg_match("/^[.]/",$target_item))
           || (!is_dir("../Users/$item/processed/$target_item"))){
          if ((substr($target_item, 0, 1) == '.'))
             continue;      
          }
      }
      $srcfile= ("../Users/$item/processed/".$target_item);
      $dstfile= ("processed/".$target_item);
      copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
      unlink($srcfile);
endforeach;
array_map('unlink', glob("processed/*.zip"));
?>
```

honestly i dont know what is going wrong with it since its duplicate is running just fine. Right now it is only moving one of the files instead of moving all of them. As I said its duplicate works just fine if you would like me to post that as well let me know.

Comment: Nest your code properly and you'll see more easily that moving the files isn't inside the foreach, so it will only move one file

Comment: Just some advice, many more people will look at your question if you indent your code when copying it into SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moving logic is outside the loop, I suppose here is the proper version:

```
$folders = scandir('../Users/');
foreach($folders as $item)
{
    if ((substr($item, 0, 1) == '.') || (preg_match("/\.php$/", $item)))
        continue;
    if (is_dir("../Users/$item"))
    {
        $target_folders = @scandir("../Users/$item/processed/");
        foreach($target_folders as $target_item)
        {
            if ((!preg_match("/^[.]/",$target_item)) || (!is_dir("../Users/$item/processed/$target_item")))
            {
                if ((substr($target_item, 0, 1) == '.'))
                    continue;
                $srcfile= ("../Users/$item/processed/".$target_item);
                $dstfile= ("processed/".$target_item);
                copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
                unlink($srcfile);
            }
        }
    }
}
array_map('unlink', glob("processed/*.zip"));
```